# Copy mysql data from local to remote server

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

I want to regularly copy the new data from local mysql server to remote mysql server. I tried exploring and found data mirroring as one solution. Unfortunately my hosting doesn't allow editing of my.cnf therefore I can't go ahead with that. Can someone else recommend any other efficient way of doing it?